# json to array in php index error

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a json text like this:

```
$text ='{"id":"12","count":"1","1":{"gkey":"g_c5218"},"0":{"gkey":"g_4b4c6"}}';
```

I want convert it to array:

```
$arr = json_encode($text,true);
```

Now I want call `$arr['id']` But I get index error.

what is  my wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) - change an array to the json

[`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) - change json to the array/object

You should use `json_decode`.